# LDAP configuration to whitesource which uses YAML. How do I approach this to use LDAP configuration?

Tags: authentication, configuration, ldap, saml-2.0, openldap

I am trying to migrate our companies Active Directory using LDAP to whitesource, however it does not officially support LDAP. I am trying to see if there is a way to install SAML on my LDAP which could enable whitesource to connect to my LDAP using SAML. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not really use SAML to migrate user identity information from AD to some other identity silo.

However you could use ADFS (on top of AD) to act as an SAML IdP, WhiteSource as SAML SP and then perform SAML 'autofederation' to populate the identity silo on the SP side with some specific identity attributes.

I don't know whitesource though. (https://whitesource.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/WD/pages/547356829/WhiteSource+SAML+2.0+Integration ?)